# If I mix https websites with non https videos - what happens?

Tags: https, html5-video

Suppose I have a website protected with ssl.  It has a video tag, and the video tag uses a URL such as http://www.somesite.com/somevideo.mp4.   I assume that the video would not be encrypted.  Now lets assume that the video comes from the same website, and so has a prefix of https.  Would it be encrypted?

Now lets suppose that the website is not protected with SSL, but the video URL comes from a https site that is.  Will the video be encrypted?

And in general, is there a problem with mixing the two?  For instance, if by a mistake a video from the same site (assuming the site is ssl protected) is put in the src attribute of the video tag without the https prefix, what will happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I haven't played with html5 video, I can confidently say that http requests employ a non-encrypted transport; and https requests employ an encrypted transport.

When a browser is rendering an https page, subsequent http content requests generally produce a warning that unencrypted requests are being made subsequent to the page's encrypted request  (e.g. Chrome and Firefox show a little warning icon near the URL).

When a browser is rendering an http page, subsequent https content requests produce no warning.